# Can't access part of Pandas dataframe by multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new with Pandas so this is basic question. I created a Dataframe by concatenating two previous Dataframes. I used

```
todo_pd = pd.concat([rabia_pd, capitan_pd], keys=['Rabia','Capitan'])
```

thinking that in the future I could separate them easily and saving each one to a different location. Right now I'm being unable to do this separation using the keys I defined with the concat function.

I've tried simple things like

```
half_dataframe = todo_pd['Rabia']
```

but it throws me an error saying that there is a problem with the key.

I've also tried with other options I've found in SO, like using the 
`_get_values('Rabia'),`or the`.index._get_level_values('Rabia')`features, but they all throw me different errors regarding that it does not recognize a string as a way to access the information, or that it requires positional argument: 'level'

The whole Dataframe contains about 22 columns, and I just want to retrieve from the "big dataframe" the part indexed as 'Rabia' and the part index as 'Capitan'.

I'm sure it has a simple solution that I'm not getting for my lack of practice with Pandas.

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
df1 = todo_pd.xs('Rabia')
df2 = todo_pd.xs('Capitan')
```